# how to make a one to one relationship in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-one

I have two tables "donor" and " location", every donor has one location in a time.
how to make the keys for this relation?
I tried to make a foreign key in location table to the donor but it gives me this message:

```
Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE `location` ADD  CONSTRAINT `location_donor` FOREIGN KEY (`donor_id`) REFERENCES `blood_donation`.`donor`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  (`blood_donation`.`#sql-23f8_2e`, CONSTRAINT `location_donor` FOREIGN KEY  (`donor_id`) REFERENCES `donor` (`id`))
```

Comment: Do you have already some inserted lines ??

Comment: yes actually in donor table.

Comment: I think you must trancate tables (remove all lines) before doing the `ALTER TABLE` statment .

Comment: I will add an answer for the question to help other poeple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute `ALTER TABLE` statment you should truncate the table in the first place.

Because Mysql can not add the constraint to the existing rows according to the error log :

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`